# Unable to restart apache after changing document root

Tags: apache, fedora, lamp

I am new with apache installation and stuff.

I am using fedora 20, installed apache , php , mysql . I can access apache test page when the document root is default to /var/www/html

But as soon as i change my document root and restart apache it throws error.

I tried googling and did lot of experiments but nothing helped.

These are the errors i am getting after changing document root and restarting :

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service
>
> Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the command it suggests?

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

Post the output of that here, and that might give more clues.

Also, you might try turning off SELinux temporarily and seeing if that solves the problem. If it does, it'll be a labelling thing. Try

```
setenforce 0
```

as root, and then try restarting the service:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

and see if you get the same error. Quite a lot of the time, if you have a headache of this sort that you can't resolve, it turns out to be an SELinux thing.

Comment: Thanks ... SE-Linux was the pain